# Why does reversing a linked list in Python leave head unchanged?

Tags: python, linked-list

I mocked up some code for reversing a linked list. No matter what I do, the head passed into the function remains as the same node. I want the original head passed into the function to be the new beginning of the linked list, which is at the end of the old one.

```py
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next
    
     def __str__(self) -> str:
         newList = []
         
         while self != None:
             newList.append(self.val)
             self = self.next
            
         return str(newList)

class Solution:
    def ReverseLL(self, head):
        """Triple pointer approach. Head node doesn't change.
        Speed: O(N)
        Space: O(1)
        """
        #init pointers
        prevNode = head
        prevPrevNode = None
        
        while head != None:
            #advance head
            head = head.next
            
            #reverse link
            prevNode.next = prevPrevNode
            
            #advance pointers
            prevPrevNode = prevNode
            prevNode = head
          
        #print(head)
        head = prevPrevNode #shouldn't this set head correctly?? Seems to but l1 remains at 2
        print(f"During: {head}")
        
        #return prevPrevNode
            
sol = Solution()
l1 = ListNode(2)
l1.next = ListNode(4)
l1.next.next = ListNode(3)
l1.next.next.next = None

print(f"Before: {l1}")
#print( sol.ReverseLL(l1) )
sol.ReverseLL(l1)
print(f"After: {l1}")
```

Output:

```
Before: [2, 4, 3]
During: [3, 4, 2]
After: [2] #should be same as during
```

Comment: Assigning to the local variable `head` has no effect on the caller's variable.

Comment: `ReverseLL` should return the new head. Then the caller can do `l1 = sol.ReverseLL(l1)`

Comment: @Barmar So is there no way to change the passed in data structure? I thought objects in Python were pass by reference.

Comment: @Bamar And if that's the case, why did the other nodes of the linked list change? In that case, output after the function call should be the same as before.

Comment: You can change what the `next` pointers in each object points to. But you can't change what a variable points to.

Comment: This is why linked lists are often split into two classes: `List` and `Node`. The `head` pointer belongs to the `List` class, and `List.reverse()` can reassign it.